# How do I get my div to collapse again once it's been opened using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I copied someone's code on a similar question, and after some messing around, I finally got it to work - now if you click 'Expand' on my website, some more text will appear - but it won't collapse once you press collapse. 

 my website: www.bestdarkdesign.tumblr.com (not really a website, it's on tumblr)  
I'm not good at all with jQuery, so any help would be appreciated. Here is the jQuery code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $(".header").click(function () {
      $header = $(this);
      $content = $header.next();
      $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
         $header.text(function () {
           return $content.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
       });
     });
  });
});
```

Here is what my html does:

Expand

- This is just some random content.
- This is just some random content.
- This is just some random content.
- This is just some random content.

Comment: can you include your html as well?

Comment: I included it, but it just showed up as actual html. My website, that I didn't have earlier is this [link](http://bestdarkdesign.tumblr.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lmsts2c0/

Basically you just need this. When you click the header, it grabs it's children (the list) and toggles it open/closed. If it's not a list, you can change 'li' to whatever that element is, 'p', 'div' etc:

```
$(".header").click(function () {
   $(this).children('li').toggle();
 });
```